# In the counting sort why we must store the cumulative sum of the elements of the count array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, counting-sort

```
for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
{
    c[i] = c[i] + c[i - 1];
}
```

Here is the code, but I can't understand why should cumulative sum of the elements.

Comment: I think https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/ might help you.

Comment: You may also take advantage from [about counting sort algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076037/about-counting-sort-algorithm) and [two ways of doing counting sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175924/two-ways-of-doing-counting-sort).

Answer (score 4):

The [counting sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/) algorithm is used to order a sequence of elements belonging to a given range. For concreteness, suppose we are ordering a subset of natural numbers, contained in the interval `[min, max]`.

To understand the algorithm, it is useful to start from the result we want to obtain. So, let us assume that the ordered sequence looks like

```
m1, m1, m1, ..., m1, m2, m2,...,m2,.... m_l, m_l,..., m_l
|----------------|   |-----------|      |--------------|
      k1 times          k2 times           k_l times
```

In other words, our ordered sequence contains the element `m1` `k1` times, the element `m2` `k2` times, etc, and `m1 < m2 < ... < m_l`.

If you want to assign a position index to each element of the sequence above, you would get

```
index                 element
1                     m1
2                     m1
....
k1                    m1
k1+1                  m2
k1+2                  m2
....
k1+k2                 m2
....
k1+k2+...+k_(l-1)+1   m_l
k1+k2+...+k_(l-1)+2   m_l
....
k1+k2+...+k_(l-1)+k_l m_l
```

As you can see from this table, each element `m_i`, which is repeated `k_i` times, appears with indexes from `k1+...+k_(i-1)+1` to `sum_i=k1+...+k_i`, where `sum_i` is the sum the frequencies up to the index `i`.

The counting sort algorithm works precisely in this way.

- You first determine the frequency of each element (the numbers `k_i`). With a range `[min,max]`, you obtain a set of `max-min+1` frequencies (some of them possibly zero).
- You then compute the partial sums `sum_i` of each `k_j`s up to a given index `i`
- Then to output the sorted sequence, you loop through the indexes, from `i=1` to `i=max-min+1`. For each index `i` such that `k_i > 0`:

  a) you set the position of `m_i` to `sum_i`

  b) decrease `sum_i` by 1

  c) repeat a) and b) until `sum_i==0`

Answer (score 1):

The counting sort algorithm has three steps. What you're looking at there is step 2.

Here's the full algorithm:

1. Create an empty array of buckets corresponding to each of the possible values in your input (for a `char` array, this would be an array of 256 `ints`). For each value in the input list, increment the value stored in the corresponding bucket.
2. Convert the bucket values into cumulative totals.
3. Create an empty array with as many elements as the input list. Then for every element in the input array, decrement the cumulative total for this element and use the resulting value as an index to place this element in the output array.

The end result is that the output list is filled with the elements of the input list.

Here's a brief worked example (using values from 0-9):

```
Input:             2 5 4 5 8 4 5 9

Step 1:
Buckets:           0 0 1 0 2 3 0 0 1 1

Step 2:
Cumulative totals: 0 0 1 1 3 6 6 6 7 8

Step 3:
                   Cumulative totals      Output list
Input value: 2     0 0 0 1 3 6 6 6 7 8    2 - - - - - - -
Input value: 5     0 0 0 1 3 5 6 6 7 8    2 - - - - 5 - -
Input value: 4     0 0 0 1 2 5 6 6 7 8    2 - 4 - - 5 - -
Input value: 5     0 0 0 1 2 4 6 6 7 8    2 - 4 - 5 5 - -
Input value: 8     0 0 0 1 2 4 6 6 6 8    2 - 4 - 5 5 8 -
Input value: 4     0 0 0 1 1 4 6 6 6 8    2 4 4 - 5 5 8 -
Input value: 5     0 0 0 1 1 3 6 6 6 8    2 4 4 5 5 5 8 -
Input value: 9     0 0 0 1 1 3 6 6 6 7    2 4 4 5 5 5 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you got stuck at understanding what cumulative sum has anything to do with sorting the array.

This is about counting sort, which is a non-comparison based sort. How are we going to sort a list if we don't compare? By figuring out two things:

- The frequency of an item
- The starting index of that item (because an item can be repeated many times)

We already know the first thing through the count array. So how do we know the second thing?

If the smallest item of the array is repeated `n` times, then each occurrence of that item will occupy index 0 to `n - 1`.

After that comes the second smallest item, occupying index `n`.

So the starting index of each item is the cumulative frequency of all the items smaller than it.

Example:

```
Index:          0 1 2 3 4 5
Sorted:         1 1 1 3 3 4
Starting index: 0     3   5
```

There is nothing before 1, so the starting index of 1 is 0.
Starting index of 3 is `freq(1)` = 3
Starting index of 5 is `freq(1) + freq(3)` = 3 + 2 = 5

And that is exactly what we aim for when we replace the frequency values in the count array with starting index.

So we know the starting index of each item, now what?

Each index of the count array represents the item in the input array. That hasn't changed.

Now, we can create a new array for storing the items in sorted order. Iterate through each item in the input array and:

- Look up the starting index of that item: `counts[item]`
- Place the item in that index in the sorted array: `sorted[counts[item]] = item`
- Increment the starting index so the next occurrence of the item will be in the correct order: `counts[item] += 1`

Hope that helps!